# Do dapps(contract) check allowance of buyer when he calls buy function?

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20, transferfrom, allowance

When a buyer calls a `buy` function on dapp contract, some dapps check the buyer's allowance before transfer tokens(erc20). Is it usual?

Answer (score 1):

If the dapp is transferring tokens on the user's behalf (i.e. calling `transferFrom()`), then the dapp must check if the user has the proper `allowance`.

In order to use `transferFrom()`, the user must *allow* a contract to spend tokens on their behalf. To do this, the user must first `approve()` a certain amount of tokens that they are willing to the let the dapp transfer. The dapp must confirm that the user has an adequate `allowance()` before calling the `transferFrom()` function, or else it will fail.

If a simple ERC20 `transfer()` is being made, then this does not matter.